# Inheritance, promote base class members

Tags: c++, inheritance

Given the following classes:

```
template <typename DataType, size_t Dimensions>
class Vector : public std::array<DataType, Dimensions> {
//stuff
};

template <typename DataType>
class Vector2 : public Vector<DataType, 2> {
//2d specific stuff
};

template <typename DataType, size_t Dimensions>
class Line {
public:
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions>& min();
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions>& max();

private:
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions> m_min;
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions> m_max;
};

template <typename DataType>
class Line2 : public Line<DataType, 2> {
//2d specific stuff
};
```

What's the best way to have `min()` and `max()` when called on a `Line2`, return a `Vector2&` rather than a `Vector&`?  Can I promote `m_min` and `m_max` to `Vector2` within `Line2`?  Or otherwise override them and still have the `Line` base class function properly?

Comment: Do partial template specialization.

Comment: Why does `Line2` even have to inherit from `Line` if they have incompatible external interfaces?

Comment: I had it as a partial template specialization, but there was so much repeated code.  Should they share a base impl class instead?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity the reason you had so much repeated code is because your design is very strange and unidiomatic in the first place

Comment: @aaronman, then that's bad, what's the proper way?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity well I don't know what any of your classes really do but inheritance should generally be saved for very specific situations usually it just complicates things

Comment: @aaronman, in this case Vector is both a point or a vector in n-dimensional space, whereas Line is simply the line joining those two points.  There's many convenience functions, etc, which are missing from the example code, but the gist is Vector is a point (or actual vector) and Line is a line.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity composition vs inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Kerrek's suggestion of using partial template specialization together with a common base class is sensible, but you should apply the technique to the Vector type:

```
template <typename DataType, size_t Dimensions>
class VectorBase : public std::array<DataType, Dimensions> {
  // things common to all vectors here
};

template <typename DataType, size_t Dimensions>
class Vector : public VectorBase<DataType, Dimensions> {
   // nothing here
};

template <typename DataType>
class Vector<DataType, 2> : public VectorBase<DataType, Dimension> {
  // 2d specific stuff here, so for example:
  DataType& x() { return at(0); }
  DataType& y() { return at(1); }
};

template <typename DataType, size_t Dimensions>
class Line {
public:
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions>& min();
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions>& max();

private:
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions> m_min;
  Vector<DataType, Dimensions> m_max;
};
```

Now you can do:

```
Line<double, 2> myLine;
double foo = myLine.max().x();
```

You could *also* apply the technique to the Line class, but that would only be useful to add functions that are specific to 2D lines, such as perhaps computing a Voronoi diagram. You do not need any Line specialization to have Line return a 2D Vector -- that happens automatically.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the best solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to break the template down into common and special parts:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> struct LineCommon { /* ... */ };

template <typename T, size_t N> struct Line : LineCommon<T, N>
{
    Vector<T, N> & min();
    Vector<T, N> & max();
};

template <typename T> struct Line2 : LineCommon<T, 2>
{
    Vector2<T> & min();
    Vector2<T> & max();
};
```

Comment: Which class would contain `m_min` and `m_max` though?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: Wherever you think it fits best.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is, I don't think I can put them in the base class; however, the base class will need to access them.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an update, this is what I wound up doing:

Because some of the functions that would have belonged in the Base class needed to return a copy of the Vector, I would have needed to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).  But I really didn't like the skeleton code required for that.  It was overly complex.

```
template <typename derived>
struct test_base {
  derived baz() { return *static_cast<derived *>(this); }
};

template <int N>
  struct test : public test_base<test<N>> {
};

template <>
struct test<2> : public test_base<test<2>> {
  test bar() { return *this; }
};

int main() {
  test<1> a = {};
  test<2> b = {};

  auto c = a.baz();
  auto d = b.baz();
  auto e = b.bar();

  return 0;
}
```

So in a desire to seek a flatter hierarchy I resorted to some template trickery:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N>
struct test {
  void foo() {}

  template <int P=N>
  typename std::enable_if<P == 2 && P == N>::type bar() {}

  template <int P=N>
  typename std::enable_if<P == 3 && P == N>::type baz() {}
};

int main() {
  test<1> a = {};
  test<2> b = {};
  test<3> c = {};

  a.foo();
  b.foo();
  c.foo();

  b.bar();
  c.baz();

  return 0;
}
```

Which seemed to me to be a cleaner solution.  And it also allows me to write functions like:

```
template <int P=N>
typename std::enable_if<P >= 2 && P == N>::type x() { return Base::operator[](0); }
```